# Can I have SSDT Publish from Project Post Build

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-data-tools, build-server

I am trying to publish a database from a tfs gated build, I have tried a number of things and haven't succeeded yet.

We are on vs2010 and hence it gets little difficult to achieve this.

My last and incomplete try was -

- Have a post build script in sqlProject to call sqlPackage.exe with publish file name, and have a if condition on it to  check id its building inside visual studio or not.. for that I have following script that doesn't work.. I would be grateful if you can guide me on this ..

  ```
  if '$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' == 'false' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DAC\bin\SqlPackage.exe /a:Publish /pr:$(TF_BUILD_BINARIESDIRECTORY)\ReservingDatabaseSQL07.publish.xml /sf:$(TF_BUILD_BINARIESDIRECTORY)\ReservingDatabase.dacpac
  ```

Comment: Do you have any error details?

Comment: dosent like it , error code 255